# SQL db created on Azure with SSMS doesnt appear in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I created a database, and added three tables to the database using SSMS 2014. You can see them here

[image]

The problem is they dont show up on Azure. You can see that two of the above dbs are there but not the one I created (PayPalTransactions)

[image]

I'm not an expert on Azure and have exhausted my brain trying to figure out why its not there

Whats even stranger is if I add an Ado.net model to the project Im working on, using code first from database, it SEES IT and I can add it.

Comment: Have you tried to access the PayPalTransactions DB from SSMS? Does it work smoothly as expected?

How long has it been since you created the DB?

Comment: Ask https://twitter.com/azuresupport and they can look into why isn't the DB showing up on the portal

Comment: We normally create database in Azure portal first. Not the other way around.

Comment: @Shantanu wow, does it take that long, it showed up there two hours later

Comment: @dinotom, you can email vinsonyu   [ at ]Microsoft.com with your subscription ID and we could look into it as to why it took so long, normally only takes less than 10 mins.